# Выполнить функцию если выбран option с необходимым value

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, как выполнить js если выбран `option` `value` которого равен 1?

```js
function send() {
  alert( 'Выбран 1' );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="send()">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function send(select) {
  if (select.value == 1) {
    alert('Выбран 1');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="send(this)">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое